# Create a new Array from Existing array in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an existing array which is like this

```js
"activeSubject": [
        {
            "subject_id": "Class Teacher",
            "subject_name": "Class Teacher",
            "status": "2"
        },
        {
            "subject_id": "Academic Leader (Head)",
            "subject_name": "Academic Leader (Head)",
            "status": "2"
        },
        {
            "subject_id": "15",
            "subject_name": "Physics",
            "status": "2"
        }
    ]
```

I then want to create a new array which will be looking like this

```js
"new_subjects": [
        {
            "value": "Class Teacher",
        },
        {
            "value": "Academic Leader (Head)",
        },
        {
            "value": "Physics",
        }
    ]
```

I already have tried this by `map()` method

```js
var objA = this.state.activeSubject.map(o => ({
          [o]: { value: o.subject_name}
        }))
```

but it is not giving a proper array, please help me resolve this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `map` syntax is quite weird, I don't know what you tried to do, but that should be enough ;)

```js
this.state = {"activeSubject": [
    {
        "subject_id": "Class Teacher",
        "subject_name": "Class Teacher",
        "status": "2"
    },
    {
        "subject_id": "Academic Leader (Head)",
        "subject_name": "Academic Leader (Head)",
        "status": "2"
    },
    {
        "subject_id": "15",
        "subject_name": "Physics",
        "status": "2"
    }
]};

var objA = this.state.activeSubject.map(o => ({ value: o.subject_name}));
console.log(objA);
```

Comment: Not weird, just incorrect here. `foo = { [o]: v }` is identical to `foo = {}; foo[o] = v`; it's called "computed property names". It is a recent addition to the language, very welcome, but it is just the wrong thing to do in this case.

Comment: Yeah, that definitely feels overcomplicated.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) with a [object property assignment pattern [YDKJS: ES6 & Beyond]](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch2.md#object-property-assignment-pattern) and map `value` with a [short hand property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

```js
var array = [{ subject_id: "Class Teacher", subject_name: "Class Teacher", status: "2" }, { subject_id: "Academic Leader (Head)", subject_name: "Academic Leader (Head)", status: "2" }, { subject_id: "15", subject_name: "Physics", status: "2" }],
    result = array.map(({ subject_name: value }) => ({ value }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var activeSubject = [
    {
        "subject_id": "Class Teacher",
        "subject_name": "Class Teacher",
        "status": "2"
    },
    {
        "subject_id": "Academic Leader (Head)",
        "subject_name": "Academic Leader (Head)",
        "status": "2"
    },
    {
        "subject_id": "15",
        "subject_name": "Physics",
        "status": "2"
    }
];
let newSubject = [];
activeSubject.forEach((obj) => { newSubject.push({ 'value:' obj.subject_name}); });
console.log(newSubject);
```

Comment: why would you do a `forEach` on it? `.map` does this for you and was built for that

Comment: sorry... Im not used to use .map - working mostly on an old rhino engine which doesnt support .map

Comment: fair enough that is a way you can do it i guess

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work

```js
this.state = {"activeSubject": [
    {
        "subject_id": "Class Teacher",
        "subject_name": "Class Teacher",
        "status": "2"
    },
    {
        "subject_id": "Academic Leader (Head)",
        "subject_name": "Academic Leader (Head)",
        "status": "2"
    },
    {
        "subject_id": "15",
        "subject_name": "Physics",
        "status": "2"
    }
]};

let objA = this.state.activeSubject.map(({ subject_name: value}) => ({ value }));

console.log(objA)
```